# Charging an account in Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm trying to implement payments with Stripe, i'm using Stripe connect.

I'm reading documentation for "Charging through the platform" and it says:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY);
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'gbp',
  'source' => {TOKEN},
  'destination' => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
));
```

I have the `PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY`, and the `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID` (Obtained from oauth flow with stripe connect), but what is the needed `TOKEN`?

I have readed that a token can be obtained from a "stripe form", but what is the point to "connect" the stripe account if i need to request card data to my users?

Do I missed something from the flow?

Is there a way to create a token from the user account?

Do i need to create a customer?

Note: I'm newbie with stripe payments.

Comment: i have connected a user through stripe connect.
i want to charge the connected account and send that money to another connected stripe account or if it is not possible then save that charged amount to my own Main Stripe Standalone Platform account but i cant the stripe says it needs  'source' => {TOKEN},   token but i am on server side so i can not use my own form and stripe.js to generate token.
So in my case how can i charge that connected stripe account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) is used to create charges on behalf of your users. Let's say you're a marketplace for example, you allow John to sell lamps online. Then, Alice comes and wants to buy a lamp from John on your website. You use the code you mentioned before to charge Alice and send the funds to John's account directly.

It looks like what you want here though is to charge Alice for yourself instead. Alice doesn't need a Stripe account in that case. You need to collect Alice's card details using [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or building your own [form](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). This will give your a card token `tok_XXX` that you then send to your server where you use it to create a charge through the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) as explained in the charges [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges).

Comment: I just figured it just about an hour ago, but thank you! :)

Comment: @koopajah i have connected a user through stripe connect.
i want to charge the connected account and send that money to another connected stripe account or if it is not possible then save that charged amount to my own Main Stripe Standalone Platform account but i cant the stripe says it needs  'source' => {TOKEN},   token but i am on server side so i can not use my own form and stripe.js to generate token.
So in my case how can i charge that connected stripe account

Comment: @Pipe: You can't charge a connected account. You need to collect *their* card details and create a customer on the platform. You can then charge that customer on behalf of another account.